# How is the threadsafety accomplished in webapp2?

Tags: google-app-engine, webapp2

From the [webapp2 documentation](https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/app.html#thread-safe-application):

> By default, webapp2 is thread-safe when the module
>   webapp2_extras.local is available.

If I look into [the source code](https://code.google.com/p/webapp-improved/source/browse/webapp2.py#1498) I see that local is used to store the app and request. However it is my impression that there is only one app (WSGIApplication) instance shared between all threads (the one I create in my main module), so when the app instance is stored in the thread-local variable it is in fact the same instance, which means that the following code (taken from [webapp2_extras](https://code.google.com/p/webapp-improved/source/browse/webapp2_extras/mako.py#116)) is not actually thread-safe (the app from get_app is actually shared between all threads, even though it is extracted from a thread-local store):

```
app = app or webapp2.get_app()
mako = app.registry.get(key)
if not mako:
    mako = app.registry[key] = factory(app)
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

The application returned by `get_app()` is shared by different threads, but it is not necessarily the same. If you have two modules creating a `WSGIApplication`, get_app() will return different instances for them. The Mako instance is bound to a particular app, and the way it gets the current app is thread-safe.